# What is the origin of the 'no photography' rule in the House of Commons?

Tags: united-kingdom, house-of-commons, procedure

While reading through Hansard to research a separate question, I came across the [following exchange:](https://hansard.parliament.uk/commons/2022-12-13/debates/DB61C374-16B5-411C-9A29-CC3DCA119EB3/IllegalImmigration#contribution-8797FC88-366C-4B81-9838-3A8554CB1897)

> Mr Speaker: Order. Someone has flashed a camera. It is quite serious to take photographs in the Chamber. If the Member knew they had taken a photograph, I would expect them to leave the Chamber. It is totally unacceptable to disrupt the Prime Minister when he is speaking.
>
> Ben Bradley: It was an accident.
>
> Mr Speaker: I hope the photograph is deleted. Go out and have a chat with the Serjeant at Arms, because it did not look that way to me.

[Paragraph 21.36 of Erskine May](https://erskinemay.parliament.uk/section/4887/electronic-devices-phones-and-cameras/) indeed confirms that photography is against the rules of the house, but the reference for this statement is a [2013 ruling by the late David Amess](https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/column?House=1&SeriesNumber=6&VolumeNumber=570&ColumnNumber=106WH), who was chairing a  Westminster Hall debate, and a 2018 booklet entitled *Rules of behaviour and courtesies in the House of Commons*, neither of which seem likely to be the original source of this rule.

What is the origin of this rule, and what was the justification for it? In particular, I wonder whether the justification was related solely to the disruption caused by photography - as the Speaker seems to allude to in this example - or some other concern.

Comment: This guidelines show that strict rules on photography for visitors existed in 2007 https://www.parliament.uk/globalassets/documents/CPA/CPC2011/Photography-Leaflet.pdf

Comment: There are also strict rules on filming and recording which were a matter of debate when broadcasts from the chamber first started. I suggest you look at that and see if photography was mentioned.